Optimal way of chaining rotation operations for pitch and yaw
Given a velocity vector $v = [x_v, y_v, z_v]$ which I want to modify based on the pitch-angle $\theta$ and yaw-angle $\psi$, I constructed the first rotation matrix $R_\psi$ that simulates yaw by rotating $v$ around its local $z$-axis
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\psi) & -\sin(\psi) & z'_0 \\
\sin(\psi) & \cos(\psi) & z'_1 \\
z'_0 & z'_1 & z'_2
\end{bmatrix}
as well as a second rotation matrix $R_\theta$ which subsequently simulates pitch by rotating $v$ around its local y-axis.
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & y'_0 & \sin(\theta) \\
y'_0 & y'_1 & y'_2 \\
-\sin(\theta) & y'_2 & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
The vectors $y'$ and $z'$ (and also $x'$) represent the local reference frame of the rotation. They are constructed by

$x' = \frac{v}{\vert v \vert}$
$y' = x' \times [0, 0, 1]$
$z' = \frac{x' \times y'}{\vert x' \times y' \vert}$

I then wrote a simple python function that is parametrized by:

$v, p$: Initial velocity, Initial position
$\theta$: The pitch-angle
$\psi$: The yaw-angle
$n$: Number of simulation steps

In the script, based on the current velocity vector $v$ the local reference frame $x', y', z'$ is calculated, the rotation matrix $R_\psi$ is created and the velocity is updated by $v_{t+1} \leftarrow R_\psi \times v_t$. Then the local reference frame is recalculated based on the newly updated $v_{t+1}$ to gain $R_\theta$. $v_{t+1} \leftarrow R_\theta \times v_{t+1}$ is calculated to reflect the pitch modification. Based on $v_{t+1}$ the new position is calculated and these steps are repeated for $t \in [0, n-1]$.
This function is supposed to simulate incremental movement in 3d-space using only pitch- and yaw-angles.
When I provide either a small $\theta$ or $\psi$ while leaving the other at 0, I observe the expected behaviour of flying in circles (when $\theta = 0$) and flying loopings (when $\psi = 0$). However, when both are $>0$ I would expect a spiral-like ascent but I only observe odd flying patterns which I do not know how to debug.
So my question is what am I doing wrong? Why does this not properly translate to the expected movement? Thanks in advance

Why would you expect "spiral like ascent"?  A spiral would be observed with a circular orbit which I think you can attain and a linear velocity along the third axis.  Seems you are confusing pitch with Z displacement.
